# Where can I get US snowfall data with day resolution?

Tags: visualisation, weather

I need to visualize the snowfall in the USA for a given time period and city.  So you could pick a given day and get a heatmap showing the amount of snowfall at each place in the USA on that day.  Monthly or seasonal snowfall isn't granular enough for this application.

Does anyone know where I could get data like this?  (Ideally it would already be hooked up to a map so I can explore the data before building the whole thing myself.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NOAA's [National Operational Hydrologic Remote Sensing Center](http://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/earth/archive.html) has an interesting daily snowfall dataset.  Their daily archive is in KML format and goes back to 2005.

[image]